# How to take the value from the last month using a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, timestamp

It's the first time I come here so I hope my question won't be too bad. 
I'm trying to pick the data from last day, last week and last month that are stored in a mongo collection.
So actually I did:

```
  if(period.includes("daily")){
    //search for 24h before now
    DockerStatsToKeep.find({
      read: { "$gte": moment(new Date()).subtract(86400, 'second').unix()}
    });
  }else if (period.includes("weekly")) {
    //search for 168h before now (7days)
    DockerStatsToKeep.find({
      read: { "$gte": moment(new Date()).subtract(604800, 'second').unix()}
    });
  }else if (period.includes("monthly")) {
    //search for last month 
    DockerStatsToKeep.find({
      read: { "$gte": moment(new Date()).subtract(xx, 'second').unix()}
    });
  }else{
    console.error("this is not a valid period format, please use 'daily, weekly or monthly'");
  }
```

But I'm stuck for the last month and I can't find a way to do it. Because month are sometimes 30days or 31days or 29days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a momentjs you can `subtract` month as well:

```
moment(new Date()).subtract(1, 'month').unix()
```

It will also handle the transition between the years. E.g. subtract 1 month from date in January 2017 will return date in December 2016

See documentation on [subtract](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/subtract/)

Comment: Thank you for the help, yes I didn't though about checking the doc of substract, I just runned with what I knew about it ^^ Thank you ! and I guess I can do `subtract(1,'day') , subtract(1,'week') ` so my code will be better

Comment: Yes but I need to wait 8min before checking it